# C# service create registry on install

Tags: c#, registry

I am new C#, so bear with me.

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2017 community edition, which includes

1. A C# service project
2. A setup project to install the C# service.

All the install works fine and the service is running and working as well.

I want to make the installer to create some registry entries. Under

HKLM\Software\Elemer\ServiceName

On the setup project I have right clicked - View - Registry and added my items in here.
On the registry key I have:

> AllwaysCreate - `True`
>
> Condition: `<blank>`
>
> Deleteatuninstall : `True`
>
> Transitive: `False`

But this not seem to work at all.

What am I missing ???

Answer (score -1):

I had a friend who wanted me to do the same thing. He told me about a program called innosetup which is basically an intstaller maker. Check it out it was like a dream come true for me. http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php The documentation is awesome. http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection

It comes installed with sample scripts that you can based your code off of. (use to help you get started) For example when I used it I just edited the particulars from a sample script it had.